# Django: 'python manage.py sql polls' error

Tags: django

I'm following the djangoproject tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/
...

I'm at the part where it tells me to start a 'polls' app in django and input it into settings.py of the project, to let it know that polls is installed. I did everything as instructed but when I do `python manage.py sql polls`, I get the following error:

> Unknown command: 'sql'

Comment: Which django version did you install?

Comment: Well, I've selected the wrong tutorial for my version of Django. Good thing the Internet is anonymous.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why are you still looking at django version 1.4 documentation to learn django(There's an obvious banner on top of the page reminds you to upgrade), but I guess the reason is that `sql` command is deprecated in version 1.9, so most likely you installed the latest version of django and it's no longer available.

Check django website for [deprecated notice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-9).

Comment: OP can change to newer docs in bottom right corner too :) [LInk for tutorial (1.9)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/)